# Extending modules dynamically in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, hook

I am learning more about dynamically including and extending modules using metaprogramming and I found an article discussing the implementation of `#included` in the Devise gem. To include devise modules, the following line would be added into a model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable
```

This triggers the `devise` method:

```
def devise(*modules)
  options = modules.extract_options!.dup

  selected_modules = modules.map(&:to_sym).uniq.sort_by do |s|
    Devise::ALL.index(s) || -1  # follow Devise::ALL order
  end

  devise_modules_hook! do
    include Devise::Models::Authenticatable

    selected_modules.each do |m|
      mod = Devise::Models.const_get(m.to_s.classify)

      if mod.const_defined?("ClassMethods")
        class_mod = mod.const_get("ClassMethods")
        extend class_mod

        if class_mod.respond_to?(:available_configs)
          available_configs = class_mod.available_configs
          available_configs.each do |config|
            next unless options.key?(config)
            send(:"#{config}=", options.delete(config))
          end
        end
      end

      include mod
    end

    self.devise_modules |= selected_modules
    options.each { |key, value| send(:"#{key}=", value) }
  end
end
```

Then an example of an `included` method from the `Validatable` module:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.extend ClassMethods
  assert_validations_api!(base)

  base.class_eval do
    validates_presence_of   :email, if: :email_required?
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
    validates_format_of     :email, with: email_regexp, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?

    validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required?
    validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
    validates_length_of       :password, within: password_length, allow_blank: true
  end
end
```

My question is, if the `ClassMethods` module is already extended in the `devise` method (specific code block below), why is it extended to the base again in `#included`? Is it just redundancy, or do they have different behaviors?

```
# This is from the `devise` method      
if mod.const_defined?("ClassMethods")
  class_mod = mod.const_get("ClassMethods")
  extend class_mod

# This is the first line of the `self.included(base)` method
base.extend ClassMethods
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of these do the same thing so it is either a redundancy due to historical reasons (they forgot to remove) or maybe they don't rely on all of their modules having `self.included` method with `base.extend ClassMethods`